# iOS Simulator won't install my app only after cleaning the project, how could I fix it?

Tags: ios, xcode

When I try to run my app on iOS Simulator (I am running Xcode 5.1.1) it fails to install my app. After cleaning the project it runs as it should, but I have to clean my project every time I want to run it on simulator and cleaning and building all the files from a big project is a pain. Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Provide error description here, please.

Comment: The error: "iOS Simulator failed to install the application"

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset your simulator and then check. May be it will work.

Comment: It doesn't work, I've already Reset the content of the simulator, reset my macbook, still there